# Passing enum to argument of integral type

Tags: c++, overloading, implicit-conversion, enumeration, integer-promotion

Consider the following code:

```cpp
enum ABC : char
{
    a, b, c
};

void ff(char c)
{
    cout << "char\n";
}

void ff(int i)
{
    cout << "int\n";
}

int main()
{
    ff(a);  // char
}
```

May I ask why complier matches `ff(char)` instead of `ff(int)`?

---

I came up with this question when I was reading *C++ Primer* (5th Edition). On page 835, the writers state:

> ... we can pass an object or enumerator of an unscoped enumeration to a parameter of integral type. When we do so, the `enum` value promotes to `int` or to a larger integral type ... Regardless of its underlying type, objects and the enumerators ... are promoted to `int`.

My understanding to the above quote is that, when being passed to a function expecting an integral argument, an enumerator will first be casted "at least" into an `int`. So, I'm expecting the above code to call `ff(int)`. Actually, even my Visual Studio editor is showing that: (Sorry I know that we should avoid having screenshot here but I just want to show what I saw)

[image]

I also noticed that if I don't explicitly specify the underlying type for `ABC`, then `ff(int)` will be called.

So my current guess goes like this: If we don't explicitly specify the underlying type, then the object/enumerator passed to the integral parameter will first be casted into an `int`. But if the underlying type is explicitly specified, then the compiler will first try to match the overloaded function which expects the specified type.

May I ask if my guess is correct?

Comment: If you don't specify the type, it's not casted to an `int`, but usually, `int` will be the defaulted choosen type instead (implementation defined), as if you specified `int`.

Comment: I don't have the answer of the question but maybe the promotion happens only if there is no matching overload. I didn't know this rule about enumerations but I'd personally find it very annoying if the `char` overload have not been picked by the compiler since it's the closest match.

Answer (score 3):

> May I ask why complier matches ff(char) instead of ff(int)?

Because an enum with fixed underlying type can implicitly convert to its underlying type. The underlying type is `char` and thus the conversion to `char` is the most preferred candidate overload.

> So my current guess goes like this: If we don't explicitly specify the underlying type, then the object/enumerator passed to the integral parameter will first be casted into an int.

A cast is an explicit conversion. The conversion in this example is implicit.

The exact preferred conversion depends on the values of the enum. The language rule is a bit complex, so I'll copy it verbatim from the standard:

> > [conv.prom]
> >
> > A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not fixed can be converted to a prvalue of the first of the following types that can represent all the values of the enumeration ([dcl.enum]): int, unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, long long int, or unsigned long long int.
> > If none of the types in that list can represent all the values of the enumeration, a prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of the extended integer type with lowest integer conversion rank ([conv.rank]) greater than the rank of long long in which all the values of the enumeration can be represented.
> > If there are two such extended types, the signed one is chosen.

> May I ask if my guess is correct?

In this case, `int` is a correct guess because it is the first type in the list of the quoted standard rule, and it can represent all values of the enum which are 0, 1 2. But the guess does not apply universally.

Answer (score 1):

From the C++ 17 Standard (7.6 Integral promotions)

> 3 A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is
> not fixed (10.2) can be converted to a prvalue of the first of the
> following types that can represent all the values of the enumeration
> (i.e., the values in the range bmin to bmax as described in 10.2):
> **int, unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, long long int, or
> unsigned long long int**. If none of the types in that list can
> represent all the values of the enumeration, a prvalue of an unscoped
> enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of the extended integer
> type with lowest integer conversion rank (7.15) greater than the rank
> of long long in which all the values of the enumeration can be
> represented. If there are two such extended types, the signed one is
> chosen.
>
> 4 **A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is
> fixed (10.2) can be converted to a prvalue of its underlying type**.
> Moreover, if integral promotion can be applied to its underlying type,
> a prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is
> fixed can also be converted to a prvalue of the promoted underlying
> type

and (16.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences)

> (4.2) — A conversion that promotes an enumeration whose underlying
> type is fixed to its underlying type is better than one that promotes
> to the promoted underlying type, if the two are different.

So as the conversion  to the fixed underlying type char is better than the conversion of the underlying type char to int due to the integral promotions then the function with the parameter char is selected as the most viable function.

> I also noticed that if I don't explicitly specify the underlying type
> for ABC, then ff(int) will be called.

Because according the quote #3 from the section "7.6 Integral promotions" the enumeration type is promoted at least to the type `int`.

However if you will declare the enumeration for example the following way as shown in the demonstration program below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

enum ABC
{
    a = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max(), b, c
};

void ff( char c )
{
    std::cout << "char\n";
}

void ff( int i )
{
    std::cout << "int\n";
}

int main()
{
    ff( a );
}
```

then the function call will be ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the underlying type for an enum will *de facto* set it as immediately compatible with this underlying type: that's why it's the `char` version that is called in your example.

The implicit underlying type is, as usual in C/C++, `int`. It's what happens when you don't specify a type with your enum - so the `int` version is called first.

But on my compiler (MSVC2017 when I tried), **even the first case don't work**: I got a *"Call to 'ff' is ambiguous"* for the `char` version... Probably because `ABC_char` is an `enum`, not "really" a char, and not "really" an int, but is compatible with both through implicit cast.

Other calls to `ff` don't produce any error - `int` version is called without a single warning.

See below code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

enum ABC_char : char { a1, b1, c1 } ;
enum ABC_short : short int { a2, b2, c2 } ;
enum ABC_int { a3, b3, c3 } ;

void ff(char)
{
    std::cout << "char" << std::endl ;
}

void ff(int)
{
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl ;
}

int main()
{
    ff(a1) ;    // Call to 'ff' is ambiguous
    ff(a2) ;    // short int -> int
    ff(a3) ;    // int -> int
}
```

The `ff(a1)` instruction won't even compile. Compiler sees two candidate functions and don't assume any of the two.

But this code works for all calls/enums:

```
#include <iostream>

enum ABC_char : char { a1, b1, c1 } ;
enum ABC_short : short int { a2, b2, c2 } ;
enum ABC_int { a3, b3, c3 } ;

template < typename T > void ff ( T c )
{
    std::cout << typeid(c).name() << " / " << typeid(std::underlying_type_t<T>).name() << std::endl ;
}

int main()
{
    ff(a1) ;    // enum ABC_char / char
    ff(a2) ;    // enum ABC_short / short
    ff(a3) ;    // enum ABC_int / int
}
```

You could, in template, use `std::is_same` and some `constexpr` conditions to ensure that you call the "correct" behavior for your function:

```cpp
template < typename T > void ff2 ( T )
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<std::underlying_type_t<T>, char>()) {
        std::cout << "Using char version" << std::endl ;
    } else
    if constexpr (std::is_same<std::underlying_type_t<T>, int>()) {
        std::cout << "Using int version" << std::endl ;
    } else {
        std::cout << "I have luck!" << std::endl ;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ff2(a1) ;    // Using char version
    ff2(a2) ;    // I have luck!
    ff2(a3) ;    // Using int version
}
```